# Cable behaving like a low pass filter

Tags: transmission-line

In the transmission line theory you can use this circuit to describe a transmission line:
[image]
So the resistor and the capacitor form together a low pass. So each cable has to have a cutoff frequency where signals no longer get to the other end of the cable, right?

Comment: 10 more to go for what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't quite work like that. When you derive the characteristic impedance in transmission line theory sure, you use a lumped-model to get the math process started but then, as you approach the solution, you purposely make the "dimensions" of the lump approach zero and this means that what you refer to as the cut-off frequency rises to infinity and we don't care about that. For instance, a simple derivation is to consider this lumped line model: -

[image]

Each small section (having an input impedance \$Z_0\$) will join on to the next small section. So then, if you do the "fairly straightforward" math you get this impedance looking into the left port: -

$$Z_0 = R + j\omega L + Z_0||\dfrac{1}{G + j\omega C}$$

$$= R + j\omega L + \dfrac{\frac{Z_0}{G+j\omega C}}{Z_0 + \frac{1}{G+j\omega C}}$$

$$= R + j\omega L + \dfrac{Z_0}{1 + Z_0(G+j\omega C)}$$

$$Z_0\cdot \left[1 + Z_0(G+j\omega C)\right] = [R+j\omega L][1 + Z_0(G+j\omega C)]+Z_0$$

$$Z_0 + Z_0^2(G+j\omega C) = R+j\omega L + Z_0[(R+j\omega L)(G+j\omega C)]+Z_0$$

$$Z_0^2(G+j\omega C) = R+j\omega L + Z_0[(R+j\omega L)(G+j\omega C)]$$

$$\color{red}{\boxed{\text{This next part is the bit where we reduce things to zero}}}$$

The important thing next is to recognize that \$(R+j\omega L)(G+j\omega C)\$ is insignificant as the "lump" approaches zero length and we are left with: -

$$Z_0^2(G+j\omega C) = R+j\omega L$$

hence $$Z_0 = \sqrt{\dfrac{R+j\omega L}{G+j\omega C}}$$

If you looked at the equation above for high frequencies, it becomes this: -

$$Z_0 = \sqrt{\dfrac{L}{C}}$$

And is basically resistive in nature.

---

> *But when you take a signal generator with the same impedance as the
> transmission line and feed it into a transmission line with an open
> termination you can see that the reflection of the square wave has
> "slower" edges than the square wave itself*

You have to be careful here because any capacitive connection on the t-line output can screw things up - even the oscilloscope input capacitance can cause this when placed at either end. Simulation of 5 pF capacitor loading the end of an unterminated 50 Ω line: -

[image]

You can see that the edges are slower but this is wholly because of the 5 pF loading at the end of the 10 metre transmission line.

Comment: But in really long cables the signals get "slowed down". So it has to behave like a lowpass?

Comment: Slowing a signal down isn't the same as a low-pass filter. The velocity of propagation is tied into the above equations just as it is optically for light. It takes a full 8 minutes for an electromagnetic wave (light) to travel from the sun to the earth but does the medium it travel though act as a low pass filter? No, It's the same math but it's a bit faster for light in free space however, neither media act as a low pass filter theoretically @electrococuk - long cables delay a signal because the signal travels further.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. But when you take a signal generator with the same impedance as the transmission line and feed it into a transmission line with an open termination you can see that the reflection of the square wave has "slower" edges than the square wave itself

Comment: @electrococuk you have to be careful here because any capacitive connection on the t-line output can screw things up - even the oscilloscope input capacitance can cause this when placed at either end.

Comment: Ahhh ok thanks. So it is rather the oscilloscope behaving like a lowpass and the capacitance of the cable doesn't matter?

Comment: @electrococuk I reckon so.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested with simulation how long piece of TEM transmission line (=2 parallel conductors) can be presented acceptably with an LCRG-element. There's no strict limit. It depends on "what's acceptable". But the quarter of wavelength (in the line) of the highest used frequency is an easy to see landmark. Pieces longer than it presented as single LCRG-elements work like low-pass filters.

If the shortest wavelength of the signal (calculated with the velocity in the line) is longer than 4 x the line length presented by one LCRG element a chain of LCRG elements present quite well how the line works.

In Heaviside's transmission line theory the LCRG elements were infinitesimal and provided the basis to write the famous telegrapher's equations.